# Why am I getting Stale Data in my databound ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, listbox

I have a form with 2 databound listboxes and two databound comboboxes. I'm using typed datasets. The controls are bound to a pair of tables with the following schema and data from this [schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3). One `listbox` and one `comboBox` are bound to the `bar` table; the other `listbox` and `comboBox` are bound to the `foo` table.

When the SelectedIndexChanged Event fires for the foo `listBox` I get the current value for the Selected Text in the Bar `listBox` and `comboBox`.

However, when I use the foo `comboBox` and try to access the `barComboBox.SelectedText` inside the  `FooComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` event I get the previously selected value from `SelectedText` instead of the new value. The `BarListBox.Selected` gives me the current value.

Note that I use the `FooListBox` to do the selection, both event handlers function as expected.

Can anyone explain what's going on here and how to work around this?

Form Screenshot w/sample data:

[image]

The dataset designer:

[image]

The form1.cs code:

```
//Standard using statements and namespace info

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Loading DataSets and initializing here

        private void FooListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value in the bar ListBox is {0}", barListBox.Text);
        }

        private void FooComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value in the bar comboBox is {0}", barComboBox.Text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any behaviour as you Explained.

pleas check this code , Please do correct me reproduced code is wrong.

I have used Combo Box items and ListBox items are added in FormLoad as DataSource from Some webServiceMethod

**in Form1.Designer.cs**

```
this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // comboBox1
            // 
            this.comboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(32, 55);
            this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
            this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 21);
            this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            // 
            // listBox1
            // 
            this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(261, 55);
            this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
            this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(255, 95);
            this.listBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

****in Form1.cs****

```
  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("The value in the bar comboBox is "+ comboBox1.Text);
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The value in the bar comboBox is "+ listBox1.Text);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebServiceRef.CM_ServiceSoapClient soapClient = new WebServiceRef.CM_ServiceSoapClient();

        comboBox1.DataSource = soapClient.GetAllCategories();

        listBox1.DataSource = soapClient.GetAllCategories();
    }
```

I have changed the Data According to DataSource form WebService Method, Still I didn't find any issues as you exaplined your beahaviour.

Comment: Please do correct me If my approach is wrong. so that I can update you with new Answer.

Comment: I should have made it clearer in my question, but this code doesn't use databinding, it just sets item values. I'll be providing a better example in a few days.

Comment: @Aksay That is, your code doesn't use databinding and mine does, which seems to be part of the strangeness.

Comment: I have Updated the code, as you said , I have added the ITEMS as DatSource bound to the ComboBox and ListBox from WebService Method